# Show difference in days in Java/ Android

Tags: java, android

I want to differentiate between Current Date and Action Date. The difference should be shown as :

3 days ago
4 days ago and son ..

How can I achieve the same in Java using in Android?

It  does not work for me and returns the actual date itself:

```
Date d = Utils.instanceDateFormat().parse(text.toString());
                String moments = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(d.getTime(), new Date().getTime(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS,
                        DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL).toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
String currentDateInput = "23 01 1997";
String actionDateInput = "27 04 1997";

try {
    Date currentDate = myFormat.parse(currentDateInput);
    Date actionDate = myFormat.parse(actionDateInput);
    long diff = actionDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
    System.out.println ("Days: " + TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You will have to modify the `SimpleDateFormat` to fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, I could do that way however, is there any way through DateUtils ?

Comment: thank you mate. Your solution is definitely word giving  a up. However, do you know if I can use DateUtils ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get the difference between two date objects

```
public static int getDaysDifference(Date fromDate,Date toDate)
{
if(fromDate==null||toDate==null)
return 0;

return (int)( (toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the minimum resolution of SECONDS_IN_MILLIS to DAYS_IN_MILLIS like this --->
`DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(date , System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.DAYS_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL).toString()`

Using that all your future dates will be resolved to in X days and past dates to X days ago with exception of previous day which gets resolved to Yesterday but that would require a minor tweak if you need it to resolve to 1 day ago.

Hope this solves the issue

Comment: tried mate and it is notworking.